# List Comprehension,Why do we get the Output that we are getting for the above code, Why is the if statement working in such a manner?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']
short_planets = [planet for planet in planets if len(planet) < 6]
short_planets
```

Comment: What other output do you think it should have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above is the same as this:

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']

short_planets = []

for planet in planets:
    if len(planet) < 6:
        short_planets.append(planet)
        
print(short_planets)
```

If statement counts characters in planet and if its less than 6, the planet is appended to short_planets list

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into an iPython REPL and gave it a go.  It appears to be working as expected (see below).  If you are running the code in .py file, however, you will need to use `print(short_planets)` to see the contents of `short_planets` since scripts behave differently in that regard than the Python REPL or REPL-like environments like Jupyter Lab.

```
planets = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'Uranus', 'Neptune']
   ...: short_planets = [planet for planet in planets if len(planet) < 6]
   ...: short_planets
Out[1]: ['Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to why the `len(planet)` works as it does, string objects are iterable in python and using `len()` will get you the `character length` in a given string. Consider the first of the planets -

```
list(planets[0])
## ['M', 'e', 'r', 'c', 'u', 'r', 'y']
```

The iterable cast in a list shows that each element of the list is a character type, and when you use `len()` it gets you the number of characters in that list.

---

If your question is around the syntax of `list comprehensions`, there are a few ways to add if conditions to them.

Without a list comprehension, you would write this down as -

```
short_planets = []
for planet in planets:
    if len(planet)<6:
        short_planets.append(planet)
        
print(short_planets)

##['Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars']
```

This is exactly the same as writing a list comprehension with a condition at the end. The condition checks each element of the list before adding it to the output list. Syntax - `[item for item in list if condition]`

```
[planet for planet in planets if len(planet) < 6]

##['Venus', 'Earth', 'Mars']
```

You can check the length of each planet using -

```
[(planet,len(planet)) for planet in planets]

#[('Mercury', 7),
# ('Venus', 5),
# ('Earth', 5),
# ('Mars', 4),
# ('Jupiter', 7),
# ('Saturn', 6),
# ('Uranus', 6),
# ('Neptune', 7)]
```

Finally, if you want to add an else condition along with the list comprehension, you will have to follow a slightly different syntax.

`[True_value if condition else False_value for item in list]`

In this case, we could just check for each element if they are less than `<6` in character length.

```
[True if len(planet)<6 else False for planet in planets]

## [False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

I would recommend checking out some good guides on how to work with list comprehensions. Here is [one of them](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/).

Answer (score -1):

Your full code is:

```
short_planets = []
for planet in planets:
    if len(planet) < 6:
        short_planets.append(planet)
```

Why do list comprehensions work?

Because this is the way Python was programmed